# HTML5 video player gives errror when loading video located inside device using Ionic-v3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, html5-video, ionic-webview

I'm developing an app using Ionic. One of the required features is letting the user upload videos to the application and seen them inside the app.

When I try to load the video using a `<video>` tag I get the following error:

`"DEMUXER_ERROR_COULD_NOT_OPEN: FFmpegDemuxer: open context failed"`

I already tried loading external videos and they load fine. I also made sure that I could access that location displaying local images without problems.

I'm using:

- Ionic V3
- cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.1
- cordova-android 7.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with the video I was using. It got corrupted when I tried to convert it to another format.

Comment: Why the downvote? This was a valid answer to the problem I was having, and I posted it so I could help other people with the same issue.